# How can I obtain the number of unique ids that fits into two criteria non simultaneously (e.g. in different rows)?

Tags: r, dplyr, count, unique

I have a `dataframe` with multiple `rows` per individual (`id`). I want to obtain the `count` of `unique` individuals who has ever recorded `1` in `A` and `B`, but not necessarily on the same day (`A` and `B` can receive `1` in different `rows`, e.g. date).

```
id <- as.character(c(108, 108, 111, 111, 111, 111, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153))
date <- as.POSIXct(c("2014-03-12 08:44:18 UTC", "2015-09-16 02:56:00 UTC",  
"2015-10-24 08:09:11 UTC", "2016-12-11 17:17:00 UTC", "2017-08-06 18:26:00 UTC", 
"2018-01-29 00:00:00 UTC", "2014-04-17 08:40:10 UTC", "2015-09-16 02:56:00 UTC", 
"2015-11-12 13:15:00 UTC", "2016-12-16 17:10:09 UTC", "2017-08-10 04:11:00 UTC", 
"2018-01-29 00:00:00 UTC"))
A <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
B <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
df <- data.frame(id, date, A, B)  
df

    id                date A B
1  108 2014-03-12 08:44:18 1 0
2  108 2015-09-16 02:56:00 1 0
3  111 2015-10-24 08:09:11 1 0
4  111 2016-12-11 17:17:00 1 0
5  111 2017-08-06 18:26:00 1 0
6  111 2018-01-29 00:00:00 0 1
7  153 2014-04-17 08:40:10 0 1
8  153 2015-09-16 02:56:00 0 1
9  153 2015-11-12 13:15:00 1 0
10 153 2016-12-16 17:10:09 1 0
11 153 2017-08-10 04:11:00 1 0
12 153 2018-01-29 00:00:00 1 0
```

I am using the function `unique`:

```
> length(unique(df$patid[which(df$A== 1 & df$B==1)]))
[1] 0
```

But I do not get what I expect, once two individuals get `1` and `A` and `B` in different moments:

```
[1] 2
```

How could I get the right count for what I want? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different `dplyr` approach which returns an integer. This makes use of `any`, which returns `TRUE` if any of the dates match the criteria.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(AB = any(A == 1) & any(B == 1)) %>%
  pull(AB) %>%
  sum()

#----
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to do it is to check for the max of A and B within a group. For example in the following way:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(Count = max(A) == 1 & max(B) == 1) %>%
  summarize(sum(Count))
```

Which results in:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  `sum(Count)`
         <int>
1            2
```